# Cannot show correct chinese character after export to csv

Tags: php, excel, csv, export-to-csv

After refer some topic in SO my export function finnally working, but problem with chinese character. After i export data from DB to csv i open with my friend pc (os win XP, MS excel 2007) with this pc i can show chinese character without any issue(in MS excel).

But when i open with my pc (os win 7, MS excel 2007) it failed to show correct character for chinese wording. Below is my output and full code.

Original data : `美不勝收價`  , after export : `ÃÀ²»RÝÊÕPù`

This export function is created to let my customers to export all products data to csv.

```
<?php
//Set maximum memory limit
ini_set('memory_limit', '50M'); 

//Load
require('includes/application_top.php'); 

//Var
$product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_id']);
$file  = 'product_export'; 

//Language
$language_array = array(
    '1' => '1',
    '2' => '4',
    '3' => '6'
);

//Chinese CODE  
$chinese_encoding =  "GB2312";  //GB2312

if(isset($product_id)) {

    //We need to escape comma and double quote
    function escape_csv_value($value) {
        $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value); // First off escape all " and make them ""
        if(preg_match('/,/', $value) or preg_match("/\n/", $value) or preg_match('/"/', $value)) { // Check if I have any commas or new lines
            return '"'.$value.'"'; // If I have new lines or commas escape them
        } else {
            return $value; // If no new lines or commas just return the value
        }
    } 

    //CSV Header
    $data = "";
    $row_output = array();
    $row_output[] = "Product Code";
    $row_output[] = "Barcode";

    $row_output[] = "Name (EN)";
    $row_output[] = "Name (CN)";
    $row_output[] = "Name (BM)";

    $row_output[] = "Model";
    $row_output[] = "Cost";
    $row_output[] = "Price";
    $row_output[] = "Quantity";
    $row_output[] = "Weight";
    $row_output[] = "Keyword";
    $row_output[] = "Image Url";

    $row_output[] = "Descrription (EN)";
    $row_output[] = "Descrription (CN)";
    $row_output[] = "Descrription (BM)";

    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 1";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 2";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 3";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 4";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 5";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 6";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 7";
    $row_output[] = "Screenshot 8";

    $row_output[] = "Manufacturer Name";
    $row_output[] = "Product ID";

    $data .= join(',', $row_output)."\n"; // Join all values without any trailing commas and add a new line

    //$values = tep_db_query("SELECT *  FROM `products` WHERE products_id IN ( ".$product_id." )");

    $values = tep_db_query("SELECT *  FROM `products` WHERE products_id='151' ");

    $row_output = array();
    while ($rowr = tep_db_fetch_array($values)) {
        $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_code"]);
        $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_bar_code"]);

        //Name
        foreach ($language_array as $lang) {
            if ($lang == '1') {
                $description1     = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_description` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and language_id='1'");
                $row_description1 = tep_db_fetch_array($description1);
                if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $row_description1["products_name"])) {
                    $products_name_UTF_1 = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($row_description1["products_name"]), $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                }
                else {
                    $products_name_UTF_1 = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($row_description1["products_name"]), $chinese_encoding, "HTML-ENTITIES");
                }
                $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_name_UTF_1);
            }
            elseif ($lang == '6') {
                $description6     = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_description` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and language_id='6'");
                $row_description6 = tep_db_fetch_array($description6);
                if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $row_description6["products_name"])) {
                    $products_name_UTF_6 = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($row_description6["products_name"]), $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                }
                else {
                    $products_name_UTF_6 = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($row_description6["products_name"]), $chinese_encoding, "HTML-ENTITIES");
                }
                $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_name_UTF_6);
            }
            elseif ($lang == '4') {
                $description4     = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_description` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and language_id='4'");
                $row_description4 = tep_db_fetch_array($description4);
                if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $row_description4["products_name"])) {
                    $products_name_UTF_4 = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($row_description4["products_name"]), $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                }
                else {
                    $products_name_UTF_4 = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($row_description4["products_name"]), $chinese_encoding, "HTML-ENTITIES");
                }
                $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_name_UTF_4);
            } 
        }


        if($rowr["products_model"]) {
            $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_model"]);
        }
        else {
            $row_output[] = " ";
        }       

        if($rowr["products_cost"]) {
            $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_cost"]);
        }
        else {
            $row_output[] = " ";
        }       

        if($rowr["products_price"]) {
            $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_price"]);
        }
        else {
            $row_output[] = " ";
        }

        if($rowr["products_quantity"]) {
            $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_quantity"]);
        }
        else {
            $row_output[] = " ";
        }

        if($rowr["products_weight"]) {
            $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_weight"]);
        }
        else {
            $row_output[] = " ";
        }

        if($rowr["products_keyword"]) {
             if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $rowr["products_keyword"])) {
                $products_keyword_UTF = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($rowr["products_keyword"]), $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                //this is chinese
            } else {
                $products_keyword_UTF = mb_convert_encoding(escape_csv_value($rowr["products_keyword"]), "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
                //this is UTF8
            }
        }
        else {
            $products_keyword_UTF = " ";
        }

        $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_keyword_UTF);

        $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_image"]);

        //Description
        foreach ($language_array as $lang) {
            if ($lang == '1') {
                $description1     = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_description` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and language_id='1'");
                $row_description1 = tep_db_fetch_array($description1);
                 if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $row_description1["products_description"])) {
                    $products_description_UTF_1 = mb_convert_encoding($row_description1["products_description"], $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                 }
                 else {
                     $products_description_UTF_1 = mb_convert_encoding($row_description1["products_description"], $chinese_encoding, "HTML-ENTITIES");
                 }

                if ($products_description_UTF_1) { 
                    $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_description_UTF_1);
                }
                else {
                    $row_output[] = " ";
                }
            }
            elseif ($lang == '6') {
                $description6     = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_description` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and language_id='6'");
                $row_description6 = tep_db_fetch_array($description6);
                if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $row_description6["products_description"])) {
                    $products_description_UTF_6 = mb_convert_encoding($row_description6["products_description"], $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                }
                else {
                    $products_description_UTF_6 = mb_convert_encoding($row_description6["products_description"], $chinese_encoding, "HTML-ENTITIES");
                }

                if ($products_description_UTF_6) {
                    $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_description_UTF_6);
                }
                else {
                    $lang6 = "1";
                }
            }

            elseif ($lang == '4') {
                $description4     = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_description` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and language_id='4'");
                $row_description4 = tep_db_fetch_array($description4);
                if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $row_description4["products_description"])) {
                    $products_description_UTF_4 = mb_convert_encoding($row_description4["products_description"], $chinese_encoding, "UTF-8");
                }
                else {
                    $products_description_UTF_4 = mb_convert_encoding($row_description4["products_description"], $chinese_encoding, "HTML-ENTITIES");
                }
                if ($products_description_UTF_4) {
                    $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($products_description_UTF_4);
                }
                else {
                    $lang4 = "1";   
                }
            } 
        }

        if ($lang6 == '1') {
            $row_output[] = " ";    
        }
        elseif ($lang4 == '1') {
            $row_output[] = " ";    
        }

        //Screenshot
        $query_screenshot = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM `products_screenshot` WHERE products_id = '" . $rowr["products_id"] . "' and main='0' LIMIT 8");
        $ss_i = 0;
        while ($row_ss = tep_db_fetch_array($query_screenshot)) {
            $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($row_ss['thumbnail']);
            if(escape_csv_value($row_ss['thumbnail'])) {
                $ss_i ++;
            }
        }

        //Fix if screenshot no value we create dummy column for this
        $ss_i_total = 8 - $ss_i;

        for ($i=1; $i<=$ss_i_total; $i++)
          {
            $row_output[] = " ";
          }

        //Manufacturer
        $query_get_manufacturers_id = tep_db_query("SELECT * from `manufacturers` WHERE manufacturers_id='" . $rowr["manufacturers_id"] . "' ");
        $manufacturers_id_result    = tep_db_fetch_array($query_get_manufacturers_id);
        $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($manufacturers_id_result["manufacturers_name"]);

        $row_output[] = escape_csv_value($rowr["products_id"]);

        $data .= join(',', $row_output)."\n";
        $row_output = ''; // Clear the contents of the $row variable to start a new row
    }
}

$filename = $file . "_" . date("d-m-Y__H-i-A");

header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".csv");

print $data;

exit;
?>
```

Comment: Try converting to UTF16-LE and setting the appropriate BOM header for the file; try with a tab-separator rather than a comma (this varies by the MS Excel locale settings).... and use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function rather than building the lines manually

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker, i will try using fputcsv()

Comment: after try so many method i still failed to export data with chinese character(every data work fine except chinese character) .. hope someone will point me to right direction..